# If writing to multiple files often, does file I/O remain costly in PowerShell?

Tags: performance, file, powershell, optimization, io

I have a large script that parses several computers for information. At the beginning of my script, I create several files to write output to as the script finds information.

Since I want my script to work at scale (hundreds or thousands of machines), I am wondering if it is too costly to write to the files *each* time the script identifies new information. In terms of performance, should I write to the files only once (after the script finishes), or do the writes to files become inexpensive after my first write?

Comment: How much data are you dealing per computer? How many different "items" are you looking per computer?

Comment: It varies based on what files the user has. I think on average we are talking 30 KB of total data, but from 6 different sources meaning 6 different writes per computer.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be an overhead if your system resource along with the DISK I/O allow you to do that.

I would recommend you to use *.Net StreamWriter* to write the file because thats pretty fast and effective way to accomplish the need:

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "t.txt"
1..100 | % {
      $stream.WriteLine($s)
}
$stream.close()
```

Avoid locking. Do not try to access the same file in parallel. That will reduce the complexity.

And it is completely feasible if you are making sure that other heavy applications are not using the Disk I/O that time.

Hope it helps.